# Finished basement with just painted concrete walls

Tags: basement, framing, basement-refinishing

I have a house from 1955, where the basement has been finished with lighting, carpet, interior walls, etc. I don't know when it was finished, only that it was so when I moved in.

The strange thing about this basement, however, is that the exterior walls don't appear to have ever been framed and drywalled. The walls appear to be just painted on the exterior concrete foundation.

I find this really strange, but I assume it was done as a cost-cutting measure by someone who finished the basement themselves.

My question is, what should I do about this situation? Do my exterior walls need to be properly framed and drywalled? If I don't do that, what negative consequences will result? I'm trying to figure out if the benefits outweigh the cost of properly framing the basement, and whether there are any negative consequences that might arise should I choose to not frame the walls.

Comment: What climate are you in? If your basement doesn't need insulation you can certainly just use the concrete walls, if you don't dislike them.

Comment: I'd say it's simply a personal preference. Some folks might find a painted concrete wall ugly, while it may not bother others. Having the wall exposed reduces labor and repairs if the wall ever leaks, so it could actually be beneficial having the wall uncovered. It could potentially affect heating/cooling costs, though the temperature underground tends to be more consistent so it may be a benefit.